# Filter result set on $location.search() parameters AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I filter my result set on $location.search() parameters?

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in tags">
  <div ng-class="{active:tagged(tag.id)}" ng-click="filter(tag.id)">
    {{album.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The class `active` appends if the result of tagged is true.

```
filter('tagged', function () {
  return function (id) {
    //Assume "tags" is also the name of the parameter.
    //"tags" is being set by $location.search({tags:['123','456','789']});
    return ($location.search().tags.indexOf(id) != -1)?true:false;
  };
});
```

The convention inside `ng-class` is wrong but I'm using as an example to demonstrate knowledge gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use filter functions in ng-class expression, but you can simply define your `tagged` function inside the controller:

```js
app.controller('AppController',
    [
      '$scope',
      '$location',
      function($scope, $location) {
        $location.search('tags', [1, 3]);

        $scope.tags = [
          {id: 1, title: "Can't Hold Us"},
          {id: 2, title: "Just Give Me A Reason"},
          {id: 3, title: "Mirrors"},
          {id: 4, title: "Get Lucky"},
        ];

        $scope.tagged = function(id){
          return $location.search().tags.indexOf(id) !== -1;
        };

      }
    ]
  );
```

```html
<body ng-controller="AppController">

  <div ng-repeat="tag in tags">
    <div ng-class="{active:tagged(tag.id)}">
      {{tag.title}}
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/0QpnOJbsy8N8l42eKQYG?p=preview)

Comment: +1 for this. The real test was if the state of the URL parameters changed, would the bool controlling the class update accordingly. The answer is yes: http://plnkr.co/edit/s4RNrl?p=preview